# get x and y relative to the brower window of a div on a rotated div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get the x and y **relative to the browser window** of a `div#character` **inside** of a other `div#characterholder`

#characterholder is rotated by 100 degrees

Comment: Please post your current code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do, you can use `element.getboundingclientrect` in order to do so:
https://javascript.info/coordinates#element-coordinates-getboundingclientrect